# Почему не стоит пользоваться функцией std::pow для целых чисел?

Tags: c++, математика, инспекция-кода, производительность, численные-методы

Мне не раз приходилось встречать рекомендации по типу "не пользуйтесь функцией `std::pow`". В связи с чем многие дают эту рекомендацию?

```c++
void MyPow(int& a, int n)
{
    int c = a;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a *= c;
}
```

Данная функция будет быстрее, чем стандартный `std::pow`? Или данную рекомендацию дают из-за того, что `std::pow` реализован не бинарно, а линейно (вот этого я кстати не знаю бинарный он или нет)?

Comment: потому что в стандартной бибилиотеке С++ отсутствует функция pow для целых чисел?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Вынужден извиниться заранее - я хочу поговорить о применимости `pow` *вообще*, а не только для целочисленных значений.

Даже если вы хотите возводить в степень умножением - то не надо делать это столь прямолинейно, есть метод [быстрого возведения в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C) n со скоростью O(lg n).

Далее, как и любой совет, это совет, а не догма. Этот совет совершенно справедлив, например (и я его постоянно даю в таких ситуациях), когда начинают вычислять что-то типа `pow(-1,n)` (сами догадаетесь, как это вычислить быстро и точно?) или `pow(x,2)` - потому что даже в том же VC++ `pow` с целочисленной степенью в `<cmath>` реализована как (выбросил лишнее для понимания)

```
double pow(double _Xx, int _Yx) noexcept
{
    if (_Yx == 2) return (_Xx * _Xx);
    return pow(_Xx, static_cast<double>(_Yx));
}
```

Так какой смысл в постоянной проверке равно ли два - двум? :) При малых значениях степени также может оказаться, что непосредственное вычисление быстрее, чем вызов функции.

Если вы намекаете на шаблонную реализацию типа `pow<int,int>` - то, выбрасывая несущественное для понимания, в VC++ она выглядит так:

```
template<class _Ty1, class _Ty2,
    class = enable_if_t<is_arithmetic_v<_Ty1> && is_arithmetic_v<_Ty2>>> 
    _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _Ty2> pow(const _Ty1 _Left, const _Ty2 _Right)
    {   // bring mixed types to a common type
    using _Common = _Common_float_type_t<_Ty1, _Ty2>;
    return (pow(static_cast<_Common>(_Left), static_cast<_Common>(_Right)));
    }
```

Т.е. все равно сводится к обычной `pow` с плавающей точкой. Которая начинает выполнять ряд телодвижений по проверке аргументов и т.п., так что простая замена на `exp(y*log(x))` работает [несколько быстрее](https://ideone.com/kYIFHM) (впрочем, эта разница существенно зависит от используемой модели с плавающей запятой - у VC++ 2017 от практически равных при `/fp:fast` до разницы в 1.8 раза при `/fp:precise`). Кстати, думаю (точнее - знаю :), см. P.P.S.), если применить даже ваш линейный способ вычисления - он будет опережать стандартный до достаточно больших значений степени.

Точность при возведении в степень целочисленного значения также страдает, но об этом уже писали выше.

Словом, всякий инструмент хорош, когда правильно применен.

Еще одно замечание в связи с последней фразой - меня также раздражает, когда начинают использовать `pow` для вычисления какого-нибудь ряда типа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда каждый член вычисляется возведением в степень, а не умножением на *x*, или когда так же в лоб вычисляют полином, игнорируя [схему Горнера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). Здесь применение `pow` глупо не потому, что она плоха, а потому, что *здесь вообще не требуется возведение в степень*!

P.S. А вообще, в программировании, как и во многих других областях деятельности - в том же кино масса примеров - сначала нечто начинают бездумно применять везде просто потому, что научились использовать это нечто. Потом приходит отрезвление - явный ведь перебор, может, вообще нужно отказаться от такой возможности?.. И только потом приходит понимание, что все хорошо в меру и на своем месте :) Но это так, отвлеченные размышления, не относящиеся к конкретно вопросу..

P.P.S. Не выдержал - заинтересовало, а в самом деле, когда будет быстрее использовать `pow`, чем просто линейное умножение? Набросал [небольшой код](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/blob/master/exper/pow_experiment.cpp), разово просчитал (VC++ 2017), построил график...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, где-то до 30 степени лучше просто множить, чем считать экспоненту от логарифма, и где-то до 50 - если использовать `pow`. Если использовать быстрое возведение в степень - то эта кривая на графике просто не видна, так как ее значение на всем диапазоне колеблется около 0.25-0.3 мс..

Comment: Браво! Побольше бы таких объяснений.

Comment: Попробовал `exp2(log2)` - получилось еще быстрее, хотя у меня разница с `pow` не такая сильная: http://quick-bench.com/AM18GUV5_BUlA5rIPhB-M1VagvQ

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я вот сейчас перезапустил бенчмарк по вашей ссылке, и получилось, что `exp2(log2)` даёт такое же время, как `pow`, а вот `exp(log)` при этом быстрее ))  Фиг знает от чего это всё зависит, но результат явно неустойчивый )

Comment: `pow` и `mul` на графике сравниваются в районе 55. Самое маленькое целое число, которое имеет смысл возводить в степень - это двойка. А самый большой стандартный целочисленный тип - 64 бита. Итого `pow` обгонит `mul` только если вы считаете двойку в степенях от 55 до 63. Во всех остальных случаях или переполнение или `mul` быстрее.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Это если делать это целочисленно, но тогда уж  `1<<n` еще быстрее :). Но никто же не мешает возводить в степень число с плавающей точкой...

Comment: ТС показал в прототипе два int'а. Я показал что скорость - не аргумент в этом случае. Я считаю что скорость - не аргумент в большинстве случаев.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Напомню первую фраpe из моего ответа: **я хочу поговорить о применимости pow *вообще*, а не только для целочисленных значений**. Да, и если не скорость вычислений, то что тогда? Кстати, тогда большинство задач должны решаться перебором :)

Comment: До скорости идет правильность: с целыми аргументами проблема в переполнениях и точности. С вещественными аргументами точность выходит на первый план. Но спорить тут не о чем. Ваше мнение - самое популярное: "считать надо быстро, а что считать не так уж важно".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну и где я хоть раз говорил "что считать не так уж важно"? :) О точности... У меня сейчас проблемы с электроэнергией, так что ruSO приходится немного откладывать в пользу основной работы, так что не хотите заняться и сравнить точности вычислений указанными методами и через `pow`? Я не могу пообещать заняться этим сразу, чтобы ответить обоснованно, но ставлю на то, что — кроме разве что N-кратного умножения — точность страдать не будет.

Answer (score 2):

В вашей реализации pow - ошибка: она дает неверный ответ для нулевого n (и для отрицательных). Не говоря уже о том, что она не поддерживает дробные n.

Стандартная pow - быстрее, она работает за константное время (независимое от n) и может быть реализована несколькими инструкциями процессора `pow(x,y)==exp( log(x)*y )`. Но! Она преобразует числа в double и обратно, что может привести к потере точности т.к. 64-bit int - содержит больше значащих цифр, чем мантисса в double.

Comment: точность много от чего зависит, регистры у современных x86 FPU 80-разрядные и точность сильно зависит от того, как долго оптимизатор держит значение в регистрах не выгружая в память. То есть с выключенной оптимизацией точность будет заведомо меньше

Comment: @PavelGridin, я думаю, что от того, выгружеы ли значения из регистров в память, может зависеть не точность, а скорость - ну, загрузит опять из памятив регситры. Потратится на несколько наносекунд больше. Но на точность это не должно влиять, иначе результат одного и того же вычисления был бы разным в разных случаях. Кстати, я думаю, сам совет "не пользуйтесь функцийей POW" тянется с тех далеких времен (борланд си и т.п.) когда сама функция pow уже была реализована через вычисления с экспонентой, а сопроцессоры были не на всех компах, и поэтому на типичном компьютере это тормозило.

Comment: @S.H., так и есть результат одного и того же вычисления в разных случаях разный

Comment: @PavelGridin, я читал несколько популярных статей (на тему сопроцессора, например https://habr.com/ru/post/503034/). Но судя по этим стаьям там всё - детерминировано. Не могли бы Вы дать мне какую нибудь информацию о том, в каких случаях результат одного и того же вычисления в разных случаях разный? Спасибо.

Comment: надо взять что-нибудь интегральное, хороший пример БПФ написанное на C/C++, просто скомпилировать и сравнить результат для Release и Debug. Поэтому нельзя проверить правильность расчётного алгоритма простым бинарным сравнением, приходится сравнивать результаты статистическими методами

Comment: @S.H., смотрите пример в конце [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1146272). Выгрузка значений из регистров в память напрямую влияет на конечный результат вычислений.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто: функция std::pow принимает в качестве параметра число с плавающей запятой, двойное или длинное двойное число и возвращает то же самое в качестве возвращаемого типа. Это вообще не целочисленно-совместимая функция. Благодаря неявным приведениям (превращению одного типа в другой) это все равно может работать.

Я бы посоветовал вам открыть сайт https://godbolt.org/ и поэкспериментировать с ним, изучая дизассемблированный код.

Answer (score -1):

> Мне не раз приходилось встречать рекомендации по типу "не пользуйтесь функцией Pow". В связи с чем многие дают эту рекомендацию?

Дурная рекомендация, дело нехитрое. Функцию `pow()` использовать можно, и даже обязательно нужно, как минимум, в юнит-тестах.

Я уж и не знаю, специально, с определённым умыслом, в вопросе дана именно такая, достаточно странная реализация функции `MyPow()`, или так просто случайно вышло. Но это хорошая иллюстрация почему `pow()` следует использовать. В самом деле, если взглянуть на результаты тестов:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

void MyPow(int& a, int n)
{
    int c = a;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a *= c;
}

template<typename I>
I ipow(I a, I b) {
    if(a == 1 || b == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    if(is_signed<I>::value && b < 0) {
        return (a == 0 ? numeric_limits<I>::min() :
                a != -1 ? 0 : 
                b&1 ? -1 : 1);
    }
    
    I ret = 1;

    while(b) {
        if(b&1) {
            ret *= a;
        }
        a *= a;
        b >>= 1;
    }

    return ret;
}

#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>

#ifdef COMPARE_POWL
    typedef long double dtype_t;
#else
    typedef double dtype_t;
#endif
static_assert(numeric_limits<dtype_t>::is_iec559, "Соответствие IEEE 754");

template<typename I>
void test_ipow(int verbose = 1) {
    I start = 0;

    if(is_signed<I>::value) {
        start = -5;
    }

    I finish = 0;

    while(pow<dtype_t>(finish, finish) <= (dtype_t)numeric_limits<I>::max() &&
          pow<dtype_t>(finish, finish) 
                    <= pow<dtype_t>(2, 1 + numeric_limits<dtype_t>::digits)) {
        finish++;
    }
    --finish;

    if(verbose) {
        cout << "test_ipow<" 
            << boost::core::demangle(typeid(I).name()).c_str()
            << ">(): start " << start
            << " finish " << finish
            << '\n';
    }

    for(I a = start; a <= finish; a++) {
        for(I b = start; b <= finish; b++) {
            if(verbose >= 2) {
                cout << a << ", " << b
                    << " -> " << ipow(a, b) 
                    << ", " << pow<dtype_t>(a, b) 
                    << ", " << (I)pow<dtype_t>(a, b)
                    << '\n';
            }
            assert(ipow(a, b) == (I)pow<dtype_t>(a, b));
        }
    }

    const I check_start = 3;
    const I check_finish = (I)trunc(cbrt(numeric_limits<I>::max()));
    intmax_t total_power = 0;
    int max_diff = 0;
    int min_diff = 0;
    intmax_t sum_diff = 0;
    intmax_t cnt_diff = 0;

    for(I a = check_start; a <= check_finish; a++) {
        I fi = (I)trunc(log((dtype_t)numeric_limits<I>::max())/log(a));

        for(I b = check_start; b <= fi; b++) {
            dtype_t d = pow<dtype_t>(a, b);
            I i = ipow(a, b);
            I diff = i - (I)d;
            total_power++;
            if(diff) {
                int idiff = (int)diff;
                assert(abs(idiff) <= d*numeric_limits<decltype(d)>::epsilon());
                if(verbose) {
                    cnt_diff++;
                    sum_diff += idiff;
                    if(idiff < min_diff) {
                        min_diff = idiff;
                    }
                    if(idiff > max_diff) {
                        max_diff = idiff;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(verbose) {
        cout << "Total power: " << total_power
            << " Total diff: " << cnt_diff
            << " Mean diff: " << (dtype_t)sum_diff/cnt_diff 
            << " Min: " << min_diff
            << " Max: " << max_diff
            << '\n';
    }
}

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        int a = 2;
        MyPow(a, i);
        cout << "MyPow(2, " << i
            << ") -> " << a
            << " - " << pow(2, i)
            << (a == pow(2, i) ? ": норма\n" : ": ОШИБКА\n");
    }

    test_ipow<int>();
    test_ipow<unsigned>();
    test_ipow<int64_t>();
    test_ipow<uint64_t>();

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
$ clang++-mp-15 -O3 -I/opt/local/include MyPow.cpp && ./a.out 
MyPow(2, 0) -> 2 - 1: ОШИБКА
MyPow(2, 1) -> 4 - 2: ОШИБКА
MyPow(2, 2) -> 8 - 4: ОШИБКА
MyPow(2, 3) -> 16 - 8: ОШИБКА
test_ipow<int>(): start -5 finish 9
Total power: 1669 Total diff: 0 Mean diff: nan Min: 0 Max: 0
test_ipow<unsigned int>(): start 0 finish 9
Total power: 2067 Total diff: 0 Mean diff: nan Min: 0 Max: 0
test_ipow<long long>(): start -5 finish 14
Total power: 2161089 Total diff: 1587677 Mean diff: 4.30641 Min: -515 Max: 520
test_ipow<unsigned long long>(): start 0 finish 14
Total power: 2717817 Total diff: 2108847 Mean diff: 3.56374 Min: -1032 Max: 1040
```

Можно увидеть, что аргументация против использования функции `pow()` так себе:

1. Точность. Для типа `int` для которого предназначена `MyPow()` функция `pow()` абсолютно точна, а функция `MyPow()` всегда выдаёт странный результат. Функция `powl()` для Intel/AMD без SSE/AVX абсолютно точна до uint64_t;
2. Понятность, доказательность, корректность интерфейса. Функция `pow()` - часть стандартов POSIX/C/C++, а `MyPow()`, прошу прощения, но это ж "колхоз на коленке". Любой, кто читает вызов `MyPow(a, 0)` или `MyPow(a, 1)` некоторое время будет считать, что это возведение в 0 и в 1 степень, но, через некоторое время будет обескуражен, что это совсем не так;
3. Производительность. И в части производительности `MyPow()` не блещет, во многом, благодаря своему странному интерфейсу, т.е. если компилятор видит её определение и может обеспечить inline подстановку, то ещё более менее, для неслишком больших степеней даже сможет немного обогнать `pow()`, но при раздельной трансляции - беда;

Понятно, что как любая библиотечная функция `pow()` является определённым компромиссом и в каждом конкретном случае может быть, в идеале, заменена на более лучший вариант. Но это ж только в идеале, в частности, при условии понимания автором кода численных методов и соответствующем документировании кода.

В части использования `pow()` для плавающих и комплексных чисел, можно отметить:

- Почти всегда, `pow(x, 2)` и `pow(x, 3)` можно заменить на `x*x` и `x*x*x`, хотя я и не уверен в пользе такой замены для `pow(x, 2)`;
- Также не стоит использовать `pow(x, 0.5)` и `pow(x, 1./3.)`, вместо `sqrt(x)` и `cbrk(x)`, хотя для `pow(x, 0.5)` это вопрос только производительности;
- В соседних ответах сравнивают производительности `pow(x, y)` с `exp(y*log(x))` или с `exp2(y*log2(x))`, но такое сравнение имеет весьма ограниченную ценность, поскольку даже выражение `exp2(y*log2(x))` всегда вычисляется с гораздо худшей точностью. Если диапазон данных ограничен, то можно рассмотреть замену `pow(x, y)` на комбинацию `expm1()` и `log1p()`, но это ж для тех, кто понимает.

Уточнение по результату замечания @wololo, добавлен `static_assert(numeric_limits<dtype_t>::is_iec559, "Соответствие IEEE 754");`.

Comment: `Для типа int ... функция pow() абсолютно точна. Функция powl() ... абсолютно точна до uint64_t` Ни стандарт арифметики с плавающей точкой IEEE 754, ни стандарты языков C и C++ не требуют абсолютно точного результата для функции `pow`, даже если точный результат представим типами `double`, `int` или `uint64_t`. Это сильнейший аргумент против использования данной функции в _целочисленных_ выражениях. И реализации с неаккуратной имплементацией данной функции существуют: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/137699), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782217).

Comment: @wololo, насчёт IEEE 754, это Вы совершенно зря, функция pow() входит в раздел "9.2 Recommended correctly rounded functions", т.е. если не происходит исключения `inexact` (9.1.1), результат должен быть точен и правильно округлён. Что до ошибок, то известны даже ЦП у которых операция умножения с ошибкой, как, впрочем, и в некоторых версиях SunOS библиотечная арифметическая операция была с ошибкой (лично находил, Sun hot-fix делал). Тут, уж все под Богом, но и тестировать программы надо, а не абы как.

Comment: 1) 9. **Recommended** operations. Clause 5 completely specifies the operations **required** for all supported arithmetic formats. **This clause** specifies additional operations, **recommended** for all supported arithmetic formats. 2) A conforming function shall return results correctly rounded for the applicable rounding direction for all operands in its domain. The **preferred quantum is language-defined**. 3) 9.2 **Recommended** correctly rounded functions ... names of the operations in Table 9.1 do not necessarily correspond to the names that any particular programming language would use.

Comment: @wololo, да, Вы верно цитируете требования точности и корректности округления IEEE 754-2008. Стандарт языка может внести **документированную** неточность, но POSIX/C/C++, по-моему, холодно ссылаются на IEEE 754. Хотя и не требуют обязательной поддержки IEEE 754. Впрочем, приведенный тест `test_ipow<unsigned>()` обеспечивает полное тестирование, кроме возведения в 0, 1 и 2 степени. Как и `test_ipow<uint64_t>()` в случае использования `powl()` и `long double` на Intel/AMD.

Comment: @wololo, для уточнения корректности теста добавил `static_assert(numeric_limits<dtype_t>::is_iec559, "Соответствие IEEE 754");`.

Comment: 1) `POSIX/C/C++, по-моему, холодно ссылаются на IEEE 754`. Стандарт языка C ссылается вполне конкретно в `Annex F (normative) IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic`. В разделе `F.3 Operators and functions` перечислены операторы и функции, выполняемые в соответствии с IEEE 754, и функции `pow` там нет, как и подавляющего большинства (если не всех) функций из таблицы рекомендованных в IEEE 754. Раздел `F.10 Mathematics <math.h>` повторно поясняет, что функции, напрямую специфицируемые IEEE 754, перечислены в `F.3`: `3 The functions that IEC 60559 specifies directly are identified in F.3.`

Comment: В черновике стандарта C23 пошли ещё дальше и всю тригонометрию, логарифмы, экспоненты и конечно же `pow` свели в одну таблицу и подписали: `The C functions in the following table correspond to mathematical operations recommended by IEC 60559. However, correct rounding, which IEC 60559 specifies for its operations, is not required for the C functions in the table.` 2) `numeric_limits<dtype_t>::is_iec559` — это не обязывает функцию `pow` считаться правильно.

Comment: @wololo, я Вас умоляю, все эти "not required" создают возможность для **документированного** отклонения от IEEE 754. Но, по крайней мере, в стеках реализаций Linux Standard Base/SUSv4/POSIX/C/C++ и MacOS/POSIX/C/C++ в документации для `pow()` нет таковых отклонений. Кроме одного: в SUSv4/POSIX указан приоритет требования SUSv4/POSIX перед ISO C. Но конкретные требования есть только в самом IEEE 754. Как, впрочем, и причин для отклонения от IEEE 754 не особо видно. А ссылки на старые ошибки в старых gcc/glibc, ну тут дело такое, и в ЦП/ОС/исполняющих систем компиляторов тоже не гарантируют.

Comment: @Serge3leo и регулярно отклоняются с и без документирования. Примеры GPU-компиляторов, компиляторов для специализированных платформ этим занимаются на завтрак, обед и ужин. Компилятор от Intel (для CPU) - тоже имеет особенности вычислений, где точность страдает там, где они необязательна по стандарту. Так что это вовсе не экзотика - это только то с чем я сталкивался за последние пару лет.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, ошибки есть у всех и всегда, я сталкивался и с ошибками ЦП, и с ошибками целой арифметики разных компиляторов и/или ядер ОС, жизнь большая, мир большой, граблей много. Но, если ваша реализация `MySuperIpow()` отличается от `pow()` то с вероятностью 99,9...% или выше ошибка в `MySuperIpow()`. «Как минимум, в юнит-тестах», вашего `MySuperIpow()` должно быть достаточно полное сравнение с `pow()`, тем более, что различных целых степеней не так уж и много, если Вам, по тем или иным причинам, `pow()` не подходит.

Comment: Можно сколько угодно рассуждать про требования к точности в стандартах, но на практике есть реализации, где `pow` неточна: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25678481/2752075

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, это примерно так же, как я Вам отвечу, что на практике есть процессоры с ошибкой умножения (Intel 386... модель, на вскидку, не припомню) или на практике есть ядро ОС с ошибкой деления в режиме ядра (SunOS 4.1 точную версию тоже по запросу).  Замечу, это далеко неполный список известных ошибок целочисленной арифметики.

Comment: 1) `А ссылки на старые ошибки в старых gcc/glibc ... ` Возврат функцией `pow` неточного результата ошибкой не является — это стандартизированное поведение. Сравнение с ошибками умножения в процессоре и т.п. — не корректно. 2) `все эти "not required" создают возможность для документированного отклонения от IEEE 754` Пруф на стандарт языка C, что реализации обязаны документировать отклонения от IEEE 754?

Comment: 3) `причин для отклонения от IEEE 754 не особо видно` [Документация glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html). `pow` считается на большинстве архитектур с ошибкой в 1ULP, что не соответствует _рекомендациям_ IEEE 754.

Comment: @wololo, (1) Вы это серьёзно?! Если честный `round(pow(i, j))` ошибочен для типа `int`, то ошибка `pow()` составляет `4194304 ulp`! Так и кто у Вас не примет такую ошибку?! (Для 80-бит Intel `long double` точность обеспечивает процессор, для 128-бит `long double` и `uint64_t` ошибка не должна превышать `2^49 ulp`) (3) Заглянем под капот [sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c](https://sourceware.org/git?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c;hb=refs/heads/master) видим "Worst-case error: 0.54 ULP", поэтому `(int)pow()` работает не хуже.

Comment: @wololo, Написано ж: "Функцию pow() использовать можно, и даже обязательно нужно, как минимум, в юнит-тестах.", и приложен пример юнит-теста с почти тотальным тестированием пар аргументов, их не так много ж. Что Вас так в этом месте зацепило? На любой платформе, после тотального тестирования можно использовать любую реализацию.

Comment: @wololo, (2) Строго говоря, это в IEEE 754 написано, Вы это место сами цитировали "The preferred quantum is language-defined." Проект стандарта ISO C2х, вместо "language-defined", тоже разрешает реализациям отклонения "Correct rounding, which IEC 60559 specifies for its operations, is not required for the C functions in the table", но не снимает требования "language-defined". Впрочем, POSIX/SUSv4 вообще говорят, что указания ISO C в части `pow()` и др. не действуют, а действует только IEEE 754.

Comment: 1) Вы упорно называете поведение наподобие `(int)pow(5, 2) == 24` ошибкой. Несмотря на нежелательность, такое поведение соответствует стандартам. Соответствующие цитаты из стандартов `IEEE 754` и языка C я вам привёл. Захватывающая история про `4194304 ulp` никак не делает наблюдаемое нежелательное поведение `pow` в некоторых реализациях противоречащим стандартам.

Comment: 2) Когда в IEEE 754 написано language-defined — это означает, что _стандарт языка_ должен определить поведение, и стандарт языка C поведение определяет: `correct rounding, which IEC 60559 specifies for its operations, is not required for the C functions in the table.` ---`Проект стандарта ISO C2х, вместо "language-defined", ... но не снимает требования "language-defined"` — эта фраза какая-то бессмыслица. Цитата из стандарта C `correct rounding, which IEC 60559 specifies for its operations, is not required for the C functions in the table` и есть описание того самого language-defined-behavior.

Comment: Повторяю вопрос: пруф на стандарт языка C, что реализации обязаны документировать отклонения от IEEE 754? 3) Вы сами с собой спорите что ли? `Заглянем под капот sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c видим "Worst-case error: 0.54 ULP"`. Ок, вы убедились, что ваше раннее утверждение об отсутствии причин для отклонения от  IEEE 754 ошибочно.

Comment: @wololo, очевидно, что фраза стандарта "correct rounding, which IEC 60559 specifies for its operations, is not required for the C functions in the table" не является выполнением требования IEEE 754 "The preferred quantum is language-defined", посколько не описывает собственно "quantum". А перекладывает эту ношу на реализацию.

Comment: @wolo, укажите в утверждении "Функцию pow() использовать можно, и даже обязательно нужно, как минимум, в юнит-тестах" призыв использовать именно `(int)pow(i, j)`, а, скажем, не `round(pow(i, j))`