# Цикл не останавливается

Tags: c++, циклы, ряды

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
   int k; long double sum2,x,e,y=0,sum;
   cout << "Введите точность вычисления:" << endl;
   cin >> e;
   for (x=1; x<=10;x+=1)
   {k=0;sum=0;
       while(1) {
           sum2=sum;
           y = (pow(-1, k) * pow(x, 2 * k + 1)) / (2 * k + 1);
           cout << "y"<< y <<endl;
           sum += y;
           if(fabs(sum-sum2)<=e){
               break;}
           k++;
       }
       cout << endl << "atan("<<setprecision(1) << x <<")="<<setprecision(10)<<sum;
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Вы ждёте неположительный fabs?

Comment: Да мне бы хоть какой)

Comment: У Вас неправильная формула.

Comment: Вот это меня переглючило, несколько раз смотрел и чётко видел 0 на месте e в сравнении. Прошу прощения)

Comment: Ряд расходится при x>1, может стоит добавить выражение из задания в вопрос?

Comment: cout << "y"<< y <<endl; ввел,чтобы видеть как ведёт себя y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш ряд сходится только при

```
|x| < 1
```

поэтому программа и не работает.

См. https://ideone.com/BI9i0Y

Только вот считать через `pow` - это просто издевательство! Cм., например, этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1143421/195342).