# В условии для оператора ''if'' выводит ошибку Е0137

Tags: c++

В общем, задали мне сделать программу для определения, находится точка заданая пользователем в некоторой зоне или нет, но у меня высветилась ошибка , и я не знаю как мне быть. Буду рад советам и критике по поводу оформления вопросов и самого кода!

Ошибка находится под второй открывающей скобкой после ! в
`(!((pow((x - 2), 2)) + (pow(y, 2)) = 4))`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x, y;
    cout << "Enter x: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter y: ";
    cin >> y;
    
    if ((x >= (-4) && x <= 4 && y <= 4 && y >= (-4)) && (!((pow((x - 2), 2)) + (pow(y, 2)) = 4)))
```

Comment: А какова ваша задача? Откуда взялись числа 4 и -4 и что черт возьми происходит во второй части условия?

Comment: В условии для if я хотел задать что х находится в квадрате который ограничен линиями х=4, х=-4, у=4, у=-4 , и в тоже время не находится в кругу который обозначается этой формулой (pow((x - 2), 2)) + (pow(y, 2)) = 4

Comment: Хотел бы вам также порекомендовать ТОЧНЕЕ оформлять вопрос. В вопрос обязательно должно быть чего вы хотите! Почему мне пришлось это доспрашивать? Также нет такой формулировки `кругy, который обозначается формулой ...` существует формулировка `окружности, график которой задается формулой y = ...` Ну вы же просили рекомендации по оформлению кода и вопроса:)

Comment: Понял, учту это в следующий раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так стоп.
Меня от этого начало подтряхивать. А еще в глазах зарябило.

`&& (!((pow((x - 2), 2)) + (pow(y, 2)) = 4)))`

- Функция pow принимает первым аргументом число. Однако этим числом может быть и целое выражение.

> Меняем `(x - 2)` на `x - 2`

- Функция pow в скобки брать не надо, так как это бессмысленно. Это то же, что взять в скобки просто число, типа так: (2).

> Меняем `((pow((x - 2), 2))` на `(pow((x - 2), 2)`

> Аналогично `(pow(y, 2))` меняем на `pow(y, 2)`

Получаем:
`&& (!(pow(x - 2, 2) + pow(y, 2) = 4)))`

**Ну а ошибка ваша в том**, что оператор `=` (оператор присваивания) используется для - извините за тавтологию - присваивания *значения* к   *переменной*. Оператор `==` (оператор сравнения) используется для - кхм, кхм - сравнения двух значений.

> Заменяем `=` на `==`

Comment: Кстати, еще увидел, что можно сократить еще 2 скобки. Все выражение с восклицательным знаком итак в скобках, зачем брать и его в скобки, т.е. меняем `&& (!(pow(x - 2, 2) + pow(y, 2) = 4)))` на `&& !(pow(x - 2, 2) + pow(y, 2) = 4))`

Answer (score 2):

Скажите, а как вы себе представляете вот это присваивание?

```
(pow((x - 2), 2)) + (pow(y, 2)) = 4
```

Ну, которое у вас в `if`? И на которое совершенно недвузначно указал компилятор, как вы и сами, впрочем, поняли.

Вобщем, исправьте присваивание на сравнение...

Кстати, а зачем у вас столько вообще-то ненужных скобок? это к вопросу об оформлении кода. И еще - тут вызов `pow`, как по мне, [совершенно излишний](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143442/195342).

Comment: В условии для if  я хотел задать что х находится в квадрате который ограничен линиями х=4, х=-4, у=4, у=-4 , и в тоже время не находится в кругу который обозначается этой формулой (pow((x - 2), 2)) + (pow(y, 2)) = 4

Comment: В данном случае мне это не важно, это вы @МаксимФисман ответьте :)

Comment: То есть, мне вместо = нужно поставить == что бы всё работало? Извините за такие вопросы , я недавно начал заниматься изучением с++

Comment: Один = - это присвоение. `x = y` - в переменную `x` положить значение `y`. Двойной == - проверка равенства. `if (x == y) ...` - если значение `x` равно значению `y`, то... Вы у себя попытались положить 4 в... словом, не в переменную. Как если бы написали `5 = 4` - что смысла не имеет...

Comment: Сейчас проверю код и отпишу помогло ли это.