# Почему в 2 логически одинаковых алгоритмах получаются разные ответы

Tags: c++, арифметика, длинная-арифметика

Мне нужно было написать алгоритм, который машинно независимо переводит байтовый массив, где байты лежат в формате little-endian в число.
Когда я тестил его я заметил, что на 8-байтовых числах ответ не совпадает. Методом тыка нашел как исправить этот баг, но я не понимаю почему это работает.
Для удобства на каждом шаге я выводил как байты лежат в числе, и заметил что на 2 последних шагах 2 младших байта самопроизвольно изменяются во втором варианте.
2  этих варианта логически не отличаются друг от друга, почему так происходит?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <math.h>


int main() {
  std::vector<uint8_t> test{0xE3, 0x17, 0xFF, 0x70, 0xE6, 0x18, 0xF1, 0x73};
  //правильно
  uint64_t res = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    uint64_t  buf = test[i] * pow(256, i);
    res += buf;
    std::cout << std::hex << res << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::dec << res;

  std::cout << std::endl;
  //неправильно
  res = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    res += test[i] * pow(256, i);
    std::cout << std::hex << res << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << std::dec << res;
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1143421/195342

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pow` оперирует числами с плавающей точкой, в данном случае - `double`. Он преобразует к `double` аргументы и возвращает тоже `double`.

Когда вы умножаете на него `test[i]`, он преобразуется в `double`. Это происходит одинаково в обоих примерах.

Отличие в изменении `res`. В первом случае результат умножения сначала преобразуется в `uint64_t` (с отбрасыванием дробной части), потом суммируется с `res`.

Во втором примере `res` сам преобразуется в `double`, а потом результат суммирования обратно преобразуется в `uint64_t`.

Длинное 64-битное число не влезает в [`double`, у которого только 52 бита мантиссы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), поэтому младшие биты зануляются.

Зато результат умножения `test[i] * pow(256, i)` влезает без проблем, потому что требует не больше 7 бит мантиссы...

---

Не используйте `pow` для целочисленных вычислений. Даже без этой проблемы, он может выдавать неточный ответ (например, [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25678481/2752075) получили `pow(5, 2) == 24.999...`).

Переделайте на операторах битового сдвига: `<<`, `>>`.

Comment: pow вообще использует  либо табулированную встроенную функцию , либо комбинацию экспооненты и логарифма `exp(power * log(base))` , точности ждать нельзя.