# Помогите найти ошибку в программе. Не проходит 2 тест

Tags: c++

Условие
Дана функция
f(x)=sin(−10⋅x^2+5x+10).

Для указанной точки
x
требуется определить значение производной
f′(x), а также является ли точка x экстремумом функции f(x).

Формат входных данных
Входные данные содержат вещественное число x.

Формат выходных данных
Первая строка выходных данных должна содержать значение производной в точке
x, с точностью не менее 5 десятичных цифр после запятой.

Вторая строка должна содержать YES, если точка x отстоит от точки экстремума не более чем на
10
−
5
, и NO в противном cлучае

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long double x;
    cin >> x;
    double_t radian = cos(-10 * pow(x, 2) + 5 * x + 10) * (-20 * x + 5);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(9) << radian << endl;
    if (sin(-10 * pow(radian, 2) + 5 * radian + 10) == 0)
        cout << "YES";
    else
        cout << "NO";
}
```

Программа спокойно проходит тест при числе 0, но валится при числе 0.7764046320109196
, результатом работы должны стать число 0 и YES.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, нехорошо сравнивать вещественные числа с нулём или с другим значением на точное равенство.

Во вторых, значение в точке экстремума для синуса -1.0 или 1.0 (здесь 1.0)

```
if (abs(1.0d-abs(sin(-10 * x * x) + 5 * x + 10))) <= 1e-5) cout << "YES";
```

Да, и забыл - нафига значение производной (radian) подставлять под функцию?

И мелкое - `pow` для квадрата использовать неразумно.

Ещё одно - в постановке задачи сказано проверить, что точка является экстремумом - а для этого нужно убедиться, что первая производная 0, а вторая не нулевая. Однако вывод этого не требует.

Comment: Плюсую, ради интереса - почему pow для квадрата не стоит использовать? (`pow(x, 2)` и `x * x` все равно один и тот же код сгенерируют для процессора).

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan Умный компилятор делает так, но вряд ли это гарантируется - а вдруг через экспоненту будет считаться? Конечно,  это могут быть просто личные пристрастия (в том числе по удобству чтения)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143442/195342