# Возведение в степень переменной со значением, полученным из массива

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

Имеется массив `mas[200]`, в который записаны некоторые числа.

Задача: Присвоить переменной double `x` значение из определенной ячейки массива и подставить в формулу для получения значения `y`:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++)
{   
    x = mas[n];
    (pow(x, 2) - 25)*(-1.0) = y;
    
}
```

Компилятор ругается на `pow` сразу двумя ошибками:

- Е0137 Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением
- С2106 := левый операнд должен быть допустимым значением

Замена `pow(x, 2)` на неграмотное `x*x` только меняет код первой ошибки

Comment: Я бы не называл `x`  неграмотной заменой для `pow(x,2)`... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143442/195342

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так а зачем вы пишете присваивание таким образом:

```
(pow(x, 2) - 25)*(-1.0) = y;
```

Вы таким образом пытаетесь присвоить значению слева значение справа, а значение слева является так называемым rvalue (проще говоря, в него нельзя присваивать, его можно только присваивать). Ваша проблема решается элементарной перестановкой:

```
y = (pow(x, 2) - 25)*(-1.0);
```