# Написать программу на C++ и рекурсивную функцию для вычисления значения суммы бесконечного ряда с заданной точностью

Tags: c++, рекурсия, ряды

Всем привет. Я вроде бы понимаю что такое рекурсия, но данную задачу решить не могу.
[image: Задание]

Я подсмотрел в интернете примерный код на такую задачу, но он не подходит.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    double x, E = 0.001, summ = 0.0;
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Введите -1 < x < 1: ";
    cin >> x;

    double formula = (pow(x, 2 * n + 1)) / (2 * n + 1);

    while (formula >= E)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            summ += formula;
        }

        else
        {
            summ -= formula;
        }

        n += 1;

        formula = (pow(x, 2 * n + 1)) / (2 * n + 1);
    }

    n += 1;

    cout << "Число членов ряда: " << n << endl;
    cout << "Сумма бесконечного ряда с точность 0.001: " << summ;
}
```

Надеюсь на скорейшую помощь, а самое главное - **объяснение решения** данной задачи:)

Comment: Напишите свой код, а [не ищите в Интернете](https://habr.com/ru/articles/521104/). Посмотрите, сколько [вопросов на эти темы здесь разобрано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%8b) — неужели вам не хочется разобраться [*самому*](https://www.facebook.com/factroom/posts/pfbid0DVd6xqE3B2hkximeTHXkyqQufsfVLuRhR7ay4UjJU7cfKxLbL5BFcd1i2svPWF4Sl), как это работает?...

Comment: @Harry Я пытался сам разобраться. Либо я тупой, либо хз. Я просто не понимаю данной задачи по крайней мере. А по поводу того "сколько вопросов разобрано" - коды к этим задачам не особо понятны. Объяснения к этим кодам тоже максимально непонятные.

Comment: Главная проблема заключается в том, что есть -1^n степени. И с ним я не понимаю что можно сделать, т.к. из - за него на 2 шаге при n = 1 formula становится отрицательной, поэтому цикл завершается. Я не могу понять, как можно это решить

Comment: в математике есть такая вещь, как абсолютное значение. Оно же модуль.

Comment: Я исправил решение, и теперь оно рабочее. Я понял, что от меня хотят. Но проблема в том, что это по факту не рекурсия и не функция. А как это перенести в подпрограмму и сделать через рекурсию, хз

Comment: Рекурсивная или реккурентная?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy рекурсивный. Функция вызывает функцию и т.д.

Comment: А то я вообще не понимаю, как сделать данную задачу с помощью рекурсии

Comment: Как переделать цикл (любой цикл) в рекурсию вы понимаете?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Лишь примерно. Я в рекурсии вообще не особо разбираюсь. Делал факториал числа через рекурсию, не более.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот [вариант с рекурсией](https://ideone.com/5WKlo9). Не лучший, далеко не самый эффективный, но — с рекурсией :)

```
double arctg(double x, double eps = 1e-10, int n = 0)
{
    double t = pow(x,2*n+1)/(2*n+1)*(1-2*(n%2));
    if (abs(t) > eps) return arctg(x,eps,n+1) + t;
    else return t;
}
```

Comment: Блин, да когда же вы все запомните - функция pow(x,y) является крайне медленной и не предназначена для взятия целочисленных степеней.

Comment: @Ddd Да когда ж вы научитесь читать? :) ***далеко не самый эффективный*** Мне надо было показать человеку рекурсию. Ну, а если хотите обтечь — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1143442/195342

Comment: @Harry Спасибо большое! Я сделал по вашему примеру, и всё заработало. Как я понял, рекурсия работает следующим образом:

Вычисляется значение t по формуле. Наша функция помещается в низ стека. 
После чего мы возвращаем нашу функцию с изменённой n. Наша новая функция помещается в стек. В конце концов условие становится ложным, функция возвращает t и на этом всё обрывается?

Comment: Ну, примерно так :) — мне словами объяснить сложно, но вроде верно :)