# Почему функция pow выдает неправильно значение при степени больше 22?

Tags: c++

[image: Код]

[image: значения]

**почему функция pow неправильно считает значение *5* в степени больше чем *22*
они вроде и близки , но они заканчиваются не на *0* или *5* !**

**но если мы например будем использовать функцию pow  и например введем значение *pow(5, 22)*
сразу числом *2384185791015625*, и умножим его на *5* то все посчитается верно**

Comment: Почитайте о точности вещественных чисел. А код и текстовый вывод картинкой приводить не нужно.

Comment: А лучше поищите в гугле про быстрое возведение в степень. Можно начать с бинарного

Comment: @Mister_Jesus Можно далеко не ходить :) — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1143421/195342

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не стоит пользоваться функцией std::pow для целых чисел?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1143421/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-stdpow-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb)

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что `pow` возвращает результат типа `double`, который из-за неточности вещественных чисел может оказаться, например, 24.999999999999999. Далее, т.к. тип "принимающей" переменной в вашем случае целочисленный, возвращённый `double` будет тоже преобразован в `int` (uint64_t), а при преобразовании к целому числу дробная часть отбрасывается.

В результате - 24.9999 может стать просто 24. Чем больше операций - тем больше накапливается ошибка и точность вычислений снижается.

Можете попробовать перемножать интовые числа без использования `pow()` , в таком случае преобразования типов не будет и точность должна радовать.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш компилятор из всех перегрузок [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) выбирает ту что работает с `double`:

```
double pow(double base, double exp);
```

`double` способен точно представлять целые числа в диапазоне *[1, 2<sup>53</sup>)* - в мантиссе вещественного числа *53* бита. Если целое больше чем *2<sup>53</sup>*, оно округляется - младшие биты тем или иным способом исключаются/удаляются/округляются. Проверка:

*5<sup>22</sup> = 2384185791015625 < 9007199254740992 = 2<sup>53</sup>* - это число может быть представлено точно.

*5<sup>23</sup> = 11920928955078125 > 9007199254740992 = 2<sup>53</sup>* - это число "не помещается в разрядную сетку" и будет округлено, что вы и видите.

Способа заставить `std::pow` использовать `uint64_t` для вычислений и результата я не нашёл. Вам придётся написать собственную функцию.